# python3 requests use quote instead of quote_plus

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urlencode

I use Python 3 and the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module/library for querying a REST service.

It seems that requests by default uses `urllib.parse.quote_plus()` for urlencoding, i.e. spaces are converted to `+`.

However the REST service I query misinterpretes this as `and`. So I need to encode spaces as `%20`, i.e. use `urllib.parse.quote()` instead.

Is there an easy way to do this with requests? I couldn't find any option in the documentation.

Comment: You could try encoding the url using `urllib.parse.quote()` before passing it into requests. Since it will already be encoded, requests will not try any further formatting.

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, can I do this with requests/urllib3 only and avoid loading another module (urllib)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It turns out you can!

```py
from requests.utils import requote_uri
url = "https://www.somerandom.com/?name=Something Cool"
requote_uri(url)

'https://www.somerandom.com/?name=Something%20Cool'
```

[documentation here](https://3.python-requests.org/_modules/requests/utils/) The `requote_uri` method is about halfway down the page.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, but that way I loose the nice request feature of adding just a dict as `params` to requests.get(url, params=dict), as requote_uri obviously needs the whole url. With Urllib instead, you can handle a dict: `urllib.parse.urlencode(dict, safe='/', quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)`. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. The requests library internally uses `urllib.parse.urlencode()` with the `quote_via` parameter set to `quote_plus`. I have been digging around to see if there is a way to pass that option through the pipeline via `requests.get()` and it appears that's not possible. I found [this issue thread](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/369) from several years ago that leads me to believe, due to their difficulties dealing with the percents, they eventually opted for the quote_plus route. (That can be considered a huge leap, though)

Comment: Thank you. Well, then I am now considering to switch back to urllib instead.

Answer (score 0):

for context...

add an alias to your .aliases file:

```
alias urlencode='$(which python3) -c "import sys; from requests.utils import requote_uri; print(requote_uri(sys.argv[1]));"'
```

then:

```
source .aliases && urlencode "https://www.somerandom.com/?name=Something Cool"
```

[image: screenshot]