# Bad request trying to scrape page using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to to scrape the following page using python 3 but I keep getting `HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`. I have looked at some of the previous answers suggesting to use `urllib.quote` which didn't work for me since it's python 2. Also, I tried the following code as suggested by another post and still didn't work.

```
url = requote_uri('http://www.txhighereddata.org/Interactive/CIP/CIPGroup.cfm?GroupCode=01')
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
  html = response.read()
```

Comment: If you can install the requests package by calling `python -m pip install requests` in the console. Then you'll have access to a package with a very easy to use interface.
If you can't we'll look into it.

Comment: I still get 400 when I do `request.status_code`. I used urlib since I know it, unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What is `requote_uri`?

Comment: I followed the answer as suggested in this post. I thought there is something in the url that needs to be re-quoted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349000/python3-requests-use-quote-instead-of-quote-plus

Comment: As Arount's answer suggests, it has nothing to do with python. You can even try with `wget http://www.txhighereddata.org/` and you'll get an HTTP 400 error. The server expects a User-Agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server deny queries from non human-like [`User-Agent` HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Use_in_HTTP).

Just pick a browser's User-Agent string and set it as header to your query:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.txhighereddata.org/Interactive/CIP/CIPGroup.cfm?GroupCode=01'
headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
}

request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
    html = response.read()
```